# * @param args the command line arguments

Tags: java

Dear community I was wondering the significance of the following code java using neatbeans as the IDE.

```
/**
* @param args the command line arguments
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact this is no java code but a comment.
As it starts with `/**` it is a javadoc comment.
With javadoc (a utility in the JDK) you can generate an API Documentation of your classes.
See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/overview-summary.html for example.

With `@param` you document a method parameter.